# Django-Filter returns the request object

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I was trying to dynamically filter the queryset in Django using Django-filters library in DRF but the filters send the response exactly as the same to request ie if i choose mode = transfer the response is

```
{
  "data": {
    "mode": "transfer"
  }
}
```

the filterset_class is defined in the views and queryset is passed on to it along with the request type.

**views.py**

```
from .filters import DataFilter
def get(self, request):

    query_set = ModelName.objects.all()
    queryset_filter = DataFilter(
        request.GET, queryset=query_set)
    return Response({"data": queryset_filter.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**filters.py**

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import ModelName
from common.models import MODE_CHOICES


class DataFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    currency = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    coin_type = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    mode = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        lookup_expr='iexact', choices=MODE_CHOICES)
    max_amount = filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='price', lookup_expr='gt')
    min_amount = filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='amount', lookup_expr='lt')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = ('currency', 'coin_type', 'mode',
                  'max_amount', 'min_amount')
```

The django-filters [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) suggests django-filter backend can be used by default by adding it to the DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS.
Is there some configuration that i am missing or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filterset.data` attribute is literally the data/query params you provide to `DataFilter` on initialization. In this case, you are providing `request.GET` as the data.

What you want to access is the filterset's `.qs` property, which is the filtered results. e.g.,

```py
def get(self, request):
    queryset_filter = DataFilter(request.GET, queryset=ModelName.objects.all())
    return Response({"data": queryset_filter.qs}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Note that you will likely need to serialize the filtered queryset.